# How to make simple button navigation to other view?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to make simple button navigation from one view to other ( I'm yet unsure that does this is called view or not ).

For example I have Featured.js as

```
var SearchPage = require('./Search');

class Featured extends Component {
    showSearchPage(){
        console.log('showing search page');
        this.props.navigator.push({
            title: "Search",
            component: SearchPage
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
           <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.showSearchPage()}>
              <View style={styles.row}>
                <Text style={styles.label}>Open Search Page</Text>
              </View>
            </TouchableHighlight>          
        );
    }
}

module.exports = Featured;
```

Then have Search.js as another Class very much like the Featured.js . How can i create a button in the view which on tap open Search.js view.

Currently I am getting "Can not read property push of undefined". 
How to define navigator or there is other simple way to navigate?

NOTE: I don't want to make TabBar navigation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So basically you have an app page which render either subviews depending on user actions.
First of all I suggest you use state instead of props for what you are doing (it's dynamic not static).

```
var SearchPage = require('./Search');
var Initial = require('./Initial');
var AnotherSubView = // ...

class Featured extends Component {
    getInitialState: function() {
        title: "initial",
        component: <Initial/>
        return({title:title, component:component});
    }
    showSearchPage(){
        console.log('showing search page');
        this.setState({
            title: "Search",
            component: <SearchPage/>
        });
    }

    render() {
        var title = this.state.title;
        var component = this.state.component;
        return (<div>
           <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.showSearchPage()}>
              <View style={styles.row}>
                <Text style={styles.label}>Open Search Page</Text>
              </View>
            </TouchableHighlight>
            {component}          
        </div>);
    }
}

module.exports = Featured;
```

Use getInitialState to load your first/landing subview. Then change your component on click.

By the way the props was undefined because you didn't define it =p. And you should use setProps. Anyway I think this was not the right was to proceed but so you know.

Hope it helps!

Comment: is {component} is a valid syntax ? I am getting error there.

Comment: It's simple jsx. what's wrong is probably the content of component.
Try a simple component = <div> Hello there </div> you'll see it works

Comment: I am really sorry , is this code for Reach for Website or Apps. I am doing react-native and i don't find any docs for {component} . May be did i tagged wrong for reactjs :S . react-native don't have div,span,

Comment: This is not related to react-native, what's your error ? This is simple jsx syntax nothing to do with react-native.

Comment: This is just a variable ... Try test = <TouchableHighlight ... then the rest of your component 

and render {test} it will perfectly work.
Try to identify where your error comes from but the code I suggested fits perfectly your needs I think

Comment: It seems logically should work. I got rid of the error. I tried with the test variable and its working find too. The title variable get changed too after calling showSearchPage. All is left why nothing is filling {component}. It seems the component doesn't load up and fill there.

Comment: It neither load initially and so also after the calling showSearchPage. I don't know why. I tried debugging and console loging. It does have the variable logged. :S

Comment: Do a test without loading something from requirejs. Just try with a static component = <div> hello </hello>

By the way I realized you need to write <SearchPages/> and not SearchPage otherwise it will not render =/

Comment: OMG , its working now hahaha. Thanks alot man for keeping patient and helping me. Yeah i needed <SearchPage/> not just simply SearchPage

Comment: I should have seen this before, glad it helped :)

Comment: Can you give me some advice on how to handle onPress if it happen in any of the subView ( searchPage ) in the Featured class ?

Comment: @FrançoisRichard how can I make it work for reactNative? I am using `react-navigation` module, and using Tabbed navigation style. I can not add routes for Add/Edit/Search button in there (as its visible navigation area). How can I do screen transition then? I have seen lots of details and its documentation but didn't get any clue, may be its too complex that's why I didn't get it right in my mind.